# How to add "transformations" to a prisma model field?

Tags: typescript, nestjs, prisma

### Problem

I have a model (say `User`), which has a `createdAt` field. The simplified schema.prisma file looks like so:

```
model User {
  id         String @id @default(uuid())
  createdAt  DateTime @default(now()) @db.Timestamp() @map("created_at")

  // other fields
}
```

I would like the return type of `prisma.users.createdAt` to be an instance of `luxon.DateTime`. While I could convert the date in the service layer, I would like to keep it DRY.

### Possible Solutions

Here's what I have thought of so far:

1. Make a `UserRepository` of some sort and make it implement `Prisma.UserModelDelegate<DefaultArgs>` interface.

> While this solution will work, it is going to be one hell of an effort to implement all the methods (`findFirst()`, `findUnique()`, `update()`, `delete()`, `create()`, and a lot more) just to be able to have dates.

2. I create utility functions (`convertDates()`, etc.) to then call in the service layer.

> The problem here is that others on my team could easily forget to call it in important places within their services leading to all sorts or hard to debug errors.

So, back to my original solution, how do you guys handle such a situation. Is there some feature Prisma offers that I have completely ignored or missed by chance?

**Any suggestions are appreciated, thanks! :)**